# Download PDF file from the SAS URL in react native for android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

`Need a way to download the PDF which will come in bulk and Source of file would be sas url or buffer in react native, where it should support android and iOS.`

`Try to use react-native-fetch-blob libraies` No idea how this works.

Comment: To download a file from the SAS URL in react native, you need to set the file cache.

You can use  rn-fetch-blob instead of react-native-fetch-blob.
....
...
...

RNFetchBlob
  .config({
    // add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
    // this is much more performant.
    fileCache : true,
  })
  .fetch('GET', 'http://www.example.com/file/example.zip', {
    //some headers ..
  })
  .then((res) => {
    // the temp file path
    console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())
  })

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.